# How to specify a StreamingMarkupBuilder tag name at runtime?

Tags: xml, groovy

I'm trying to build an XML document using StreamingMarkupBuilder.  I don't know what the element's tag name is until runtime, so I am trying to find a way to specify it in StreamingMarkupBuilder.bind().  I've seen how to specify element attributes, and the value, but not the tag name.  Any ideas?

```
def xmlBuilder = new StreamingMarkupBuilder()

def xmlString = xmlBuilder.bind {
    root {
        for (MyClass obj : MyClass.list()) {
            obj.getTagName(myValue)
        }
    }
}.toString()

return xmlString
```

What I am trying to get:

```
<root>
    <FoundTagName>myValue</FoundTagName>
</root>
```

**Edit**

Here's what I ended up with:

```
MyClass.list().each { f ->
    "$f.tagName"(f.getValue())
}
```

I think it's worth noting that within the double quotes I used the property name as opposed to the method name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
import groovy.xml.*

def values = [ tim:12, apples:'yum' ]

String xmlString = new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
  root {
    values.each { k, v ->
      "$k"( v )
    }
  }
}

assert xmlString == '<root><tim>12</tim><apples>yum</apples></root>'
```

Obviously, I'm using a map for my values, but you should be able to use your class (whatever it is) in a similar fashion...

Comment: Thanks; that helped a lot.  I edited my answer to incorporate what you suggested with a map with how I was working with my object.

Comment: A further question after.. a year: what if I want to externalise the `"$k"(v)` bit out into a closure? where I can reuse it for different values of `k` and also would be able to do something like null checking etc, the problem I got is simply return `"$k"(v)` from external closure will make groovy complain about undefined method signature k(String)